# Is it possible for shell script to detect whether JavaScript is running on firefox?

Tags: php, javascript, shell

I wrote an HTML page with JavaScript, a PHP file and a shell script
they are all on the same machine
I run the shell script, it will open the html page with Firefox,
when the JavaScript finishes, it will POST to a getdata.php

```
<form id="hidden_form" method="POST" action="getdata.php" ></form>
```

The getdata.php will do something and then it will send a signal to the shell script

the above is the normal behaviour, I'm afraid at some time, the PHP or JavaScript run into error and don't send signal to the shell script

are there any good and simple way for shell script to detect whether JavaScript is running?

a guy below mentioned that I can let javascript send request to the server periodically, like once every 2 minutes, but how to let shell script notice this/get the signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone suggested, you can poll the server with setInterval to see if the javascript engine is still running, but that might as well mean that only the javascript thread doing setInterval is the one actually running (depending on what kind of error could arise). You could do the post to "status.php" which would touch/write to a file on the disk, which the bash script could poll to see if it's updated in regular intervals.

I'd however suggest that you look into something like [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) which allows you to  solve these kind of problems.

Comment: when I post to the status.php, the status.php will be automatically displayed on the browser in place of the original html page, how to prevent this happening?

Comment: Use an XMLHTTPRequest call, most javascript libraries wrap this in some way (such as jQuery with $.get / $.post / $.ajax).

Comment: are there any code snippets for that? I think get and post still request that php page back to the browser

Answer (score 0):

No.

Remember: Javascript is running remotely over on the client browser; PHP (and your shell script) are on the server.

What you *can* do is set up an alarm (on the server) when you send the web page, and invoke an alarm handler if it triggers:

- http://www.woodwose.net/thatremindsme/2011/05/forking-parallel-processes-in-bash/

Comment: they are all on the same machine, I just use local apache server

Comment: the running time is varialbe, so alarm is not suitable

Answer (score 0):

If your JavaScript is running a long-to-process script, you may intermittently submit a request to the server over a set interval. If you don't see the request after a set period... ( interval x2 or w/e ) and the signal has not been received upon completion, you can assume that the JavaScript itself has stopped running / broke.

```
setInterval("methodofcommunicatingtotheserver", 1000);
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

..as stated before: No.

Your best options in this case are, either:

1. Re-design your script. Is it absolutely necessary for it to send the request to the php page via the javascript in-browser?
2. If the answer to the above is yes, have a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), especially [Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).

It does not provide bindings for bash scripts out-of-the-box, but it's pretty easy to use from other languages such as Python (or PHP, they say).